# Can child under 18 with grandparents exit Uk without grandparents?

Tags: uk, children, minors

My query is to find out if a child (Under 18) is travelling with his grandparent,  upon entry I understand he needs to make with his grandparent, as his visa will have the name of The grandparent.

My question is, can he exit UK without them, if he wants to come back earlier then his/her grandparents.

Comment: @Dorothy unfortunately, the only answer on that question doesn't actually answer the question (it addresses the question of whether the *adult* can leave first).

Comment: @phoog It asks whether a child who enters on an accompanied visa "can leave the country alone", which covers both cases. Although the asker's situation has the adult leaving first, the answer is clear that the adult and child must leave together, which precludes either the adult or the child leaving first.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes, the question is a duplicate, but the answer does not address the question. It concludes only that "it's a violation of the rules to leave the child in the UK after entering the country." No word on whether putting the child on a flight out is allowed. By my reading this is also far from clear from the quoted material.

Comment: @phoog The answer says, in boldface, that the child must travel with the adult. That means the child cannot leave before the adult, after the adult, on a different plane to the adult or anything else. I'm not sure where you're seeing any ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it seems reasonable to interpret "must travel with" as applying only at the point of entry control.  Otherwise I would expect it to say "must travel with the adult at all times while in the UK."

Comment: @phoog OK. I see your point, though I disagree with it.  (I would argue that if "must travel with" meant only "must enter with", then it would have said _that_.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby On re-reading, I am pretty sure I agree that that interpretation is incorrect: "accompanied by" obviously means "at arrival," which tends to imply that "and will be traveling with" means "after arrival."  But still, given the number of times I read that passage before I came to this conclusion, I think that questions about its meaning are reasonable.